# cattr_accessor outside of rails

Tags: ruby, google-search

I'm trying to use the [google_search](http://github.com/fox/google_search) ruby library (code follows) but it complains that '`cattr_accessor` is an undefined method' - any ideas why this might be or how I could fix it?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'google_search'

GoogleSearch.web :q => "pink floyd"
```

Comment: alert the authors of the `google_search` gem that they've got this problem. They should not depend on `cattr_accessor` from Rails IMO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cattr_accessor` seems to be a Rails extension [that acts like `attr_accessor`, but is accessible on both the class and its instances](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor).

If you want to copy the source of the `cattr_accessor` method, check out [this documentation](http://caboo.se/doc/classes/Class.html#M004152):

```
# File vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors.rb, line 46
def cattr_accessor(*syms)
  cattr_reader(*syms)
  cattr_writer(*syms)
end

# File vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors.rb, line 4
def cattr_reader(*syms)
  syms.flatten.each do |sym|
    next if sym.is_a?(Hash)
    class_eval("unless defined? @@\#{sym}\n@@\#{sym} = nil\nend\n\ndef self.\#{sym}\n@@\#{sym}\nend\n\ndef \#{sym}\n@@\#{sym}\nend\n", __FILE__, __LINE__)
  end
end

# File vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors.rb, line 24
def cattr_writer(*syms)
  options = syms.extract_options!
  syms.flatten.each do |sym|
    class_eval("unless defined? @@\#{sym}\n@@\#{sym} = nil\nend\n\ndef self.\#{sym}=(obj)\n@@\#{sym} = obj\nend\n\n\#{\"\ndef \#{sym}=(obj)\n@@\#{sym} = obj\nend\n\" unless options[:instance_writer] == false }\n", __FILE__, __LINE__)
  end
end
```

Comment: Rails 4+ use similar method mattr_accessor, as cattr_accessor is deprecated in rails 4

Answer (score 3):

You can get this functionality by including the Ruby Facets gem.  Reference the source here:

https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/cattr.rb

You generally don't need to require all code from the gem.  You can selectively require what you want.  There are quite a few useful extensions in the gem though.

Comment: This lead me to the rubyworks facets project which moved since this post https://github.com/rubyworks/facets +1 though because the end source code is good