# ruby access static variable

Tags: ruby, syntax

```
class A
  @@ololo = 1
end

A::ololo
A.new.ololo
NoMethodError: undefined method `ololo'
```

okey. I need an attr_reader

```
class B
  @@ololo = 1
  attr_reader :ololo
end

A::ololo
NoMethodError: undefined method `ololo'
A.new.ololo
=> nil
```

wtf? is there any limit for ruby accessors?

```
class C
  @@ololo = 1
  def self.ololo
    @@ololo
  end
  def ololo
    @@ololo
  end
end

C::ololo
=> 1
C.new.ololo
=> 1
```

Ruby men usually say "yeah! pretty good!". is this pretty good?
**Can anyone provide shorter code?**

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/1145995)'s something that might help you along the right track.  Its been too long since I've done anything to do with class variables and class-level instance variables to provide a proper answer though.

Comment: year this is what i am looking for! but @fl00r was the first who right it ^___^

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't do what you want to do :)

@harald is right. `attr_reader` will define GETTER only for instance variable, for "static" (aka "class variables") you need to define setter and getter by yourself:

```
class A
  @@ololo = 1

  # instance level

  # getter
  def ololo
    @@ololo
  end
  # setter
  def ololo=trololo
    @@ololo = trololo
  end

  # and class level
  # if you need it

  # getter
  def self.ololo
    @@ololo
  end
  # setter
  def self.ololo=trololo
    @@ololo = trololo
  end
end
```

So:

```
a = A.new
b = A.new
A.ololo
#=> 1
a.ololo
#=> 1
A.ololo = 100
A.ololo
#=> 100
a.ololo
#=> 100
b.ololo
#=> 100
a.ololo = 4
A.ololo
#=> 4
```

...

Shorter one:

```
class A
  @ololo = 1
  class << self
    attr_accessor :ololo
  end
end
```

Comment: write it! what the problem? :) Because there is no any `static_accessor` by default. And stay cool, man

Comment: it is not a piece of FAQ, man. I've just thought you didn't understand this Ruby idiom. That's it. If this is so obviouse for you - that's great.

Comment: the answer was **nobody needs static_accessor and it is very easy to write it yourself.** your code is the same as i do in the question

Comment: It's not a syntax trick. It's using Ruby object model the way it's supposed to be used.

Answer (score 3):

`attr_accessor :ololo` defines the methods `ololo` and `ololo=` which work against an instance variable named @ololo. So what happens when you try to access `A::ololo` ruby will find your instance method `ololo` and fail since you're trying to call it as a class method.

Comment: I am taking about static variables + attr_accessor. it doesn't work it is a fact. Please dont paste parts of accessors faq

Comment: `attr_accessor :ololo` defines an instance variable named `@ololo`. No, it doesn't. Instance variables start existing the first time you set them - they aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: why such smart ruby can't resolve difference between static and usual variable? why there are no static_accessor?

Comment: can you provide alternative solution with shorter and more pretty code?

Comment: nobody needs `static_accessor` and it is very easy to write it yourself.

Comment: my question was "is static_accessor exists? or is attr_accessor can resolve difference between usual variable and static". can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: There's no `static` in Ruby. Class methods and variables are just instance methods and variables of `Class` object

Comment: @sepp2k, you're right. I was a bit imprecise there, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

```
class A
  cattr_accessor :ololo    
  @@ololo = 1
end

class B
  A.ololo #Gets class variable "ololo" from class A
end
```

This is basically a Ruby on Rails feature.  However, outside Rails, you can obtain the functionality from the Ruby Facets gem:

https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core-uncommon/facets/module/cattr.rb

See this discussion:
[cattr_accessor outside of rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002247/cattr-accessor-outside-of-rails)