# Retain values generated during RSpec rake task after the rake task

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

I have a class like the following:

```
class Foo
  @variable = {}

  class << self
    attr_accessor :variable
  end

  def self.run(file)
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

I have an RSpec type method like the following:

```
def method?
  Foo.variable[@name] = {}
  Foo.variable[@name][:variable_two] = 'string'

  true
end
```

I have an rspec and custom task like the following:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new("rspec-#{spec}".to_sym) do |task|
  task.pattern = spec
end

desc "do stuff"
task spec do
  Rake::Task["rspec-#{spec}".to_sym].invoke
  Foo.run(spec)
end
```

I am executing the `spec` task with rake.

If I do `puts Foo.variable` in the `method?` definition, then I see that during the RSpec subtask for `"rspec-#{spec}".to_sym` the `Foo.variable` hash is populated exactly and perfectly as I expect. However, as soon as `Foo.run` executes after the rspec rake task, the `Foo.variable` hash becomes empty. I have tried many different ways to transfer or retain the values generated during the rspec rake task to the `Foo.run` method and the above code is basically the template I return to after each attempt.

What kind of algorithm gives me the functionality to retain values assigned to a variable during a rspec rake task for another method executed afterwards?

---

Tried class variable suggestion with:

```
class Foo
  @@variable = {}

  def self.variable
    @@variable
  end

  def self.run(file)
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

and same problem.

Comment: That's a very peculiar definition for a class. Where's your `initialize` if you're using instances? If not, try using [`cattr_accessor`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002247/cattr-accessor-outside-of-rails) to define it.

Comment: I have no instances for that class. I just googled the `cattr_accessor` since I have never heard of it and found out why: it is rails. This is just ruby.

Comment: If you have a class with no instances, ever, what you want is a `module` instead. `mattr_accessor` is similar to `attr_accessor` but for modules. These are in ActiveSupport, but stand-alone versions are also available.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for a class variable. Something along the lines of

```
class Foo
  @@bar = 0

  def increment
    @@bar += 1
  end

  def bar
    @@bar
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar
=> 0

f.increment
f.bar
=> 1

g = Foo.new
g.bar
=> 1

g.increment
g.bar
=> 2

f.bar
=> 2
```

Class variables, denoted with the double `@` (`@@bar` in this case), are generally considered [bad practice](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-class-vars), so please be careful when using them.

Comment: Tried it and still have the same problem. Thanks for the suggestion though.